# Swap flash video files depending on the language selected - sitecore

Tags: sitecore, sitecore-media-library

I'm learning sitecore.

I would like to render flash video which should swap between two languages depending the current language selected.

Ex:
    If I select English, I should render english version of the video and if French selected, french version of the video should render.I have both versions of the flash files.

How can i achieve this using xslt or JS? Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the xslt helper function `sc:language()` to get the current language of the page.

A rough example :

```
<xsl:choose>
  <xsl:when test="sc:language() = 'en'">
   [SHOW FLASH for EN]
  </xsl:when>
  <xsl:otherwise>
    [SHOW DEFAULT FLASH]
  </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Stephen. Tried with                       <xsl:when test="$lang='en'">. Works fine :)

Comment: Ah yes .. that works too .. always forget about that variable hiding at the top of the XSLT :)

Comment: @NSA, if Stephen's answer is helpful, consider accepting it. That what makes people more responsive to your future questions ;)

Comment: @ Yan, I didnt mean that Stephen was wrong. But i mentioned another way to solution. Anyways, will keep your suggestion in mind. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than achieve this through code, it would be a better solution to pull out a reference to your flash file from a Field in an Item in Sitecore. This could either be on the the current Item of the page the user is viewing, or if you need this across the site then on an Item referenced by your sublayout which displays the Flash video.

That way your code remains simple, and if you need to extend to other languages, you don't have to change your code; you just need to create a new translation of the item which points to a different flash file.

Comment: I like this solution. Sitecore items were designed to support multiple version in different languages out of the box. You don't need to write a single line of code. Plus maintainability of code- imagine you getting requirement to support one more language and  with approach from Stephen you need to run through all your renderings and add new switch for language. This will be painful. At the same time you can add new language version for item in few clicks.